# Creating a crosstab report with long text column data into sub report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, crosstab

I have an iReport cross tab report with questions and players and their answers. The questions are long text that are displayed as column headers, because they have long text, they don't show up and is trimmed. What I need to do is something like this

```
sorry I am unable to post an image.
```

How should I put the questions in a sub report so that the text is not trimmed in the cells?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the font size to a small amount and increase the height/width of the column header. It can be done in the properties menu when you click on the header.

Comment: Not possible, the number of columns is around 15, even setting the font size to an unreadable value will not show all the question inside cell!

Answer (score 0):

Just select the field of cross tab which has long text, and in its properties window just check the 'stretch with overflow', so whenever the report will be generated, then it will come with full text.